# What packages do I install to get WINE in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, wine

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

I tried to install WINE in 11.10 but met with some difficulties because of which I removed it. I tried to install Assassin's Creed 1 but turned to be a catastrophe.

Now I want to try again. However, I am confused as to which of these  packages am I to install, avoiding crashes, clashes, system failures system damage and ensuring running smooth installation of games.

[image: img]

I need help regarding compatibility and dependency.

I viewed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine#answer1669) and as per the update & want the latest developing branch.

## Update :

On trying to install wine through terminal, I get this error :

> **ved [ ~ ] >>>> sudo apt-get install wine**
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    wine : Depends: wine1.5 but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
>    **ved [ ~ ] >>>> sudo apt-get build-dep wine**
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Picking 'wine1.5' as source package instead of 'wine'
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: mesa-common-dev (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.2) but it is not going to be installed
>                      Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.2) but 9.1~git20121025.86cd77d0-0ubuntu0ricotz2~precise is to be installed
>    libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglu1-mesa (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.2) but 9.0.0-0ubuntu1~precise1 is to be installed
>   E: Build-dependencies for wine could not be satisfied.

I tried to install dependencies but no success. Also, `sudo apt-get -f install` didn't work. If I run `sudo apt-get -f install wine1.5`, it gives unmet dependency as

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    wine1.5 : Depends: wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.20-0ubuntu2)
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

and on attempting to install `wine1.5-i386`,

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    wine1.5-i386:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
>                                 libgl1:i386
>                        Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
>                                 libglu1:i386
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

What else do I do?

Answer (score 3):

`Wine Windows Programmloader` is wine itself.
I suggest you to use `PlayonLinux` its a great GUI for managing the installation of programms using wine and comes with many scripts for programminstalls. It will either download a preferred wine version for each programm (if there is an installscript given for that one).

[image]

Comment: So `PlayonLinux` installs WINE and an additional GUI?

Comment: Playonlinux is an additional GUI. And it will install wine for you.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to install it via terminal. (or you can use Synaptic)

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

This will install wine and all packages that are needed. In Ubuntu 12.04 it will install Wine 1.4.

If you want to use Wine 1.5 you can use a PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

If you try to install specific Windows software, you should have a look on this site: http://appdb.winehq.org/

There you can find additional infos what you need for which software.

Comment: Gives error. Can't install wine

Comment: @VedVals could you specify the error? Or is `Can't install wine` the error you get? Cheers

Comment: @Mochan Question updated with error. Tried `build-dep` with no success.

Comment: I see. Please take a look at this answer on how to solve [unmet dependencies](http://askubuntu.com/a/111713/78161), as it will probably help. If this doesn't help, let me know :)